# Advantage of using index when searching, filtering

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, filter

I have a MySQL database table where I have couple of columns one of which is varchar type having values of "Yes / No" OR a whole bunch of md5 strings.

The other 2 fields are int/tinyint with single digit/numeric values. These 2 fields are:

1. LicenseType (Values are 0 or 1)  // 0 Demo, 1 is Paid
2. Application Status (0 or 1) // 0 Expired, 1 Active

If I were to be using a query to select records that have "Yes", or filter them based on whether the LicenseType is demo or paid, or filter them based on Application Status, would it help to create indexes on those 3 columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need three single-column indexes on those 3 columns respectively if your query only filters by one of them every time(aka only one column in your where clause)

However, a three-column index like (column1, column2, column3) will help if your query is like

`select * from xxx where column1='Yes', column2=1 and column3=1`

(aka three columns in your where clause)